# Is it possible to put words inputted by a user in a file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to input a users inputted text in a separate text file, but not sure how to do that. Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: Post a small, complete script to show the context for your question along with sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

For one line:

```
read -r userline
printf "%s\n" "${userline}"> textfile
```

When you make a loop, use `>>` for appending.

Comment: how can I do this for multiple lines lets say 4

Comment: Google for `bash loop` and you get tons of examples and explanation.